# What type of cable do I use to connect to the power pins on RF equipment?

Tags: wiring

I'm using several pieces of equipment from Minicircuits, namely an amplifier and a bias-T. Each of them have a strange power connector - it looks like a small metal post with a disk on the top, or a bare wire that sticks out of insulation. See example image below:

[image]

I'd like to find cables that properly attach to this. Any input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ones with turned ridges are simple solder terminals - quite often screwing directly into the housing for a ground connection.

The plain ones (especially if they appear to be a wire potted in glass with a hex head surrounding them) are quite likely to be feedthrough capacitors, used for power or control signals.

Normally you would solder 22 gauge +/- stranded wire (or heavier if high current) onto them.  It goes best if you pre-tin both the terminal and the wire, especially for the ground terminals screwed into the housing which may take quite a bit of heat.

We used to use individual pin contacts from 2mm molex connectors in heatshrink on feedthroughs in the lab, but always directly soldered wires on shipping builds.

Answer (score 1):

I believe those are [solder terminals](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=11301K-ND).

[image]

Comment: If they are these, the proper way to connect to them is to directly solder a wire.

Answer (score 1):

Mini-Circuits has a detailed page dedicated to exactly this question, including an example photo.

https://blog.minicircuits.com/soldering-turret-terminal-pins-on-zx-series-models/

Wrap the wire into position first, then solder.

For prototyping, you might be OK with a test hook, alligator clip, etc. (Short circuits to ground should be avoided.)

There are no "proper" pluggable connectors that are intended to mate with these turret terminals.

If you're not experienced with soldering, can you find a local friend / colleague / teacher to help you solder this joint?

You don't want to damage your relatively expensive Mini-Circuits amplifiers or similar modules with excessive heat or by breaking off the power pin.

Personally, I would use very flexible silicone-insulated wire, as it's generally just very nice, and will avoid mechanical stress on the turret pin.